# How do i get rid of the sudo requirement?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

I am using MacOS Catelina and i often have to run my terminal stuff with sudo otherwise they fail. like when i use Visual Studio and IONIC to add stuff to global or when it tries to create dir etc.
Is there a way to change the logged in user to run elevated commands in terminal without sudo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either continue using sudo or switch current user to root (it's not a recommended way)

> The user account named ”root” is a superuser with read and write
> privileges to more areas of the system, including files in other macOS
> user accounts. The root user is disabled by default. If you can log in
> to your Mac with an administrator account, you can enable the root
> user, then log in as the root user to complete your task.
>
> > The root user account is not intended for routine use. Its privileges
> > allow changes to files that are required by your Mac. To undo such
> > changes, you might need to reinstall your system software. You should
> > disable the root user after completing your task.
>
> It's safer to use the sudo command in Terminal instead of enabling the
> root user. To learn about sudo, open the Terminal app and enter man
> sudo.

Taken from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204012